# Topological entropy of skew product map $F(x,y)=(f(x),g_x(y))$ in case of identical topological entropy for each fibre map $g_x$

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy

Suppose, we have a dynamical systen $(X,f)$ and a skew product $(X\times Y)$ with skew product map
$$
F(x,y)=(f(x),g_x(y))
$$
with $g_x\colon Y\to Y$ for fixed $x\in X$.

I have a questions concerning topological entropy $h(F)$ of $F$:

Do we have that
$$
h(F)=h(f)+c\qquad\text{ if }   h(g_x)=c\text{ for all }x\in X?
$$

(For example, if $h(g_x)=0$ for all $x\in X$, do we then have $h(F)=h(f)$?)

Comment: The answer is no in general. You can find in the paper "A Note on the Entropy of Skew Product Transformations" by R. Adler an example and a formula of the entropy of skew product map.

Comment: Hm, okay. Unfortunately, I do not have a measure or sth like this.

Comment: You can convert the example into a pure topological one in fact.

Comment: You can ignore the measurable structure and change it to a topological space and measure preserving transform to a homeomorphism,  and measure entropy to topological entropy. I think it still works.

Comment: And the integral turns into what?

Comment: You mean you want a formula for the entropy?

Comment: Yes, but i do not know if this is possible.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a nice formula, but since topological entropy is the supermum of the measure entropy over all invariant measures, you can get something. But I am not sure the formula, even in measurable case, can be easily used to calculate entropy except some special case.

Comment: @SimingTu The question is about the topological entropy. For the metric entropy you may know that the most general result is due to Ledrappier and Young with a far reaching Pesin formula for measures that are absolutely continuous on conditionals. They also gave a "formula" in the nonabsolutely continuous case.

Comment: @Rhjg I don't know the answer to your question. My personal guess is that the answer is yes (since there is uniform continuity on $x$).